# YouTube play getting 400 error in android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am try to play video using youtube video API

When I put static ID means declare ID in file at that time code is working.

But when I try to fetch ID from getIntent() I also got ID but video not play.

I got There was problem with network.

Below is my code.

here below my code

```
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AryAGafadXF9ECWqjdPtsahshsrJHzg";
// YouTube player view
private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
String youtubeLink;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.youtube_main);
    Intent intent =getIntent();
    youtubeLink=intent.getStringExtra("youtubeLink");
    youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);

    // Initializing video player with developer key
    youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
        errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
        String errorMessage = String.format(
                getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {

        // loadVideo() will auto play video
        // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically
        player.loadVideo(youtubeLink);

        // Hiding player controls
        player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
        // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
        getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
}

private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
}
```

}

my error

not working I got 400 Network problem error

Main activity code

```
    //youtube image display id and imageView
    youtube_image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.revi_fulldes_movieyoutubeImg);
    youtube_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent youtube= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PlayYouTube1st.class);
            youtube.putExtra("youtubeLink",youtubeLink);
            startActivity(youtube);


        }
    });

    youtubeLink=Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getYoutubeLink();


    mov_pos=Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras()).getString("mov_pos"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its happens when you give youtube full url as parameter in loadVideo(videoID) method.

```
youtubeLink=intent.getStringExtra("youtubeLink");
 //check is youtube videoID 
//not give entire youtube url
```

Give ONLY the **YouTube ID** and not the entire YouTube URL (youtubeLink)to the loadVideo() method.

Comment: yes i gave just id but i am facing this error@sasiKumar

Comment: print youtubeLink in Toast check is it correct or not?

Comment: but my code is right but where i did wrong please help me @sasikumar

Comment: post previous activity code then only check null value issue

Comment: onclick method before pass youtubeLink check value in toast

Comment: passing null value@sasikumar

Comment: how to set my Youtubelink value to string

Comment: youtubeLink=Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getYoutubeLink(); check this line get proper video Id then only problem will be solved

Comment: when i place this into text view it will displaying fine but here i am getting error